# Safely hiding API key from public view

Tags: api, vue.js, content-management-system

I am looking to try and build a simple blog with Vue.js and Butter CMS using the following guide:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/serverless-blog.html

All seems ok, however, the one thing I was wondering is how I would go about hiding the API key that I will generate from Butter CMS. I will use the CDN reference to load Butter CMS.

If anyone could advise what's the best way to hide the API key for safety - maybe using a PHP file so it's server-side or some other way that would be great as I'm not sure on the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

client side isn't safe , everybody can see your codes

you should use server side